# Array value not getting updated in shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

i have a shell script for putting values into an array. The script is working fine for me. The problem is, if i put the array inside a for loop (between do and done), and when i try to print the array length outised the loop,i.e, after done, the values are not getting updated. Here is the sameple code;

```
function _read_value
{
    count=0
    array[0]="hi" 
    for ///some condition
    do
        count++
        array[count]="hello"
    done
    echo ${#array[@]
}
```

When i try to print the length of the array at the end, it is showing the length as 1.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i'm not familiar with this but do you close the for-loop? or the do-block?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, i am using a while loop, not for. do and done is used inside the while.

Comment: ok you open and close the do-block but does your program know where your while ends? for me it looks like the "echo" is also in your while-loop.

Comment: Actually , for shell script, there is no bracket for while loop

Comment: ok. keep on tryin. doensn't seem like it's impossible to solve

Comment: If your while-loop is part of a pipeline, then it is run in a subshell, and any changes to variables in the while-body will be lost when the subshell exits. Show us your real code that exhibits the problem. Also, your sample code contains several syntax errors, so I'm skeptical that the "script is working fine".

Comment: ya.. actually the the sample script contains many typos.. sorry. But , i got it working using Raghuram's code though. Sorry for the late reply !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some small changes in your script and its updating values and the count also comes fine.(I made change in count increment and in loop)

```
#!/bin/bash
function read_value
{
    count=0
    while [ $count -le 5 ]
    do
        array[count]="hello"
        count=`expr $count + 1`
    done
    echo ${array[@]}
    echo ${#array[@]}
}

read_value
```